# Copy specific range of 2 Dimensional Char[][] Array to char * or std::string

Tags: c++, arrays, char, std

Assuming you read the title, here's a little example in pseudo code:

```
char inputChar[5][20];
{put data in array obviously}
char * outputChar;
copy(inputChar[2][7], inputChar[2][18], outputChar);
printf("%s", outputChar);
```

or optionally (although I prefer the above version):

```
char inputChar[5][20];
{put data in array obviously}
std::string outputString;
copy(inputChar[2][7], inputChar[2][18], outputString);
cout outputString; //I don't know how to use std::strings with printf
```

I've tried std::copy and memcpy but I can't get it to work. The result either gives me random characters that aren't part of the string, or just results in compiler errors due to me not understanding the syntax fully.

EDIT:
Here is the actual code I'm using:
(assume for this example that storeMenu already has data assigned to it)

```
int line = 0
int frame5 = 11;
char storeMenu[9][13];
char * temp1 = new char[12];
char * temp2 = new char[12];
std::copy(&storeMenu[line+1][0], &storeMenu[line+1][frame5-10], temp1);
std::copy(&storeMenu[line][frame5-10], &storeMenu[line][12], temp2);
```

Comment: _Show_ us the problems. Don't just say you have some.. And _explain_ what you're trying to do, in words (we can't tell from code that, by your own admission, does not accurately represent that goal)

Comment: Why post the problem in pseudo code and not in real C++?

Comment: `outputChar` or `outputString` is not a container for your items

Comment: In the first case, you're passing an indeterminate pointer as the target for `std::copy`, and even if it were determinate but not shown due to omission of *real* code, you still don't terminate the string. In the second case, you're passing a `std::string` as an argument to a parameter expected to be an iterator. *Post real code*. You say you've tried X. Don't post fantasy code that is at-best "like" X, post X. Related, `std::back_inserter(outputString)` as the third argument in your second example would probably achieve what you want, though that `cout` line afterward is obviously wrong.

Comment: What's `storeMenu`? What's `line`? Come on, don't make us ask you for every piece! :) Post an **MCVE**.

Comment: Sorry lol, didn't think about that.

Comment: "I don't know how to use std::strings with printf[.]" You're better off without `printf`, but if you must, [use `std::string::c_str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) or [use `std::string::data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

Comment: @WhozCraig First: I would try the std::back_inserter(outputString) but I need the output to be a char array because this is inside of a const char * function (returns char). Second: For your first suggestion, I'm afraid I don't know what an "iterator" is. and Third: you said I don't terminate the string (which is true) but how would I accomplish that?

Comment: @user4581301 could you show me an example of this:  
printf(RESET "\x1b[4;19H" COLOR BRIGHT CSEP WHITE CEND "%s", storeMenu[0]);  
(all the words in capitals are just in my header file defined as "\x1b[ and some color data M") and the storeMenu just returns a const char *  
anyways, show me how I would do that using cout

Comment: The simple example is `printf("%s", outputString.c_str());`, but requires `outputString` to be properly sized and terminated, something it doesn't look like you are doing in any of your examples. `outputString` is empty. It has size 0. Coping outside the bounds of a string causes undefined behaviour (C++ Standardese for "Something so wrong that we won't bother specifying what happens if you do it. Just don't do it.") After that all bets are of. The program is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `std::copy` you need a pointer to the location of the character, you are passing the character itself here. You also need to initialize `outputChar`.

```
char inputChar[5][20] = {"abc","def","ghi01234567890","jkl"};
char * outputChar = new char[20];
auto last = copy(&inputChar[2][0], &inputChar[2][5], outputChar);
*last = '\0';
printf("%s\n", outputChar);
```

Alternatively using `std::string`:

```
char inputChar[5][20] = {"abc","def","ghi01234567890","jkl"};
string outputChar;
copy(&inputChar[2][0], &inputChar[2][5], back_inserter(outputChar));
printf("%s\n", outputChar.c_str());
```

Using inputs as `std::string` too:

```
string inputChar[5] = {"abc","def","ghi01234567890","jkl"};
int fromChar = 2; // from (inclusive) ^  ^  
int toChar = 5; // to (exclusive)        ^   
string outputChar;
copy(inputChar[2].begin()+fromChar, inputChar[2].begin()+toChar, back_inserter(outputChar));
printf("%s\n", outputChar.c_str());
cout << outputChar << endl;
```

Comment: WTB a terminating nulchar, and some [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm not sure about that, but: when creating a new array on the heap, the default value is 0. And I'm not sure what you mean by RAII.

Comment: @Ra8 check 3rd code block. Why does yours work and mine doesn't?

Comment: @Ra8 "the default value is 0." - Unless the object in question is being [value-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) (and yours is *not*), or provides a default constructor that performs [default-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) exhibiting the behavior you seek (and `char` does *not*.), that is *false*.

Comment: [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii). Note this has absolutely nothing to do with the mid-90's comic Rai and the Future Force.

Comment: @Magicrafter13Gaming apparently your code works too: http://ideone.com/jizSys we would need more details to figure out why it's failing on your machine.

Comment: The reason this answer works and your version doesn’t is that in your version, `outputChar` is uninitialized. When you try to write or read to it, you get undefined behavior; I’m a bit surprised it’s random characters instead of your program crashing, but it could have been anything. Here, `outputChar` is being initialized to a newly-created array.

Comment: This has been working, but I'm trying to convert my char arrays to std::string arrays (instead of char thing[5][30] I'm basically doing std::string[5][30]) and it doesn't work with it, I can't quite figure out how to do it since the error messages are too long and elaborate since I'm using c++ std strings.